# Data from CSV placed behind each other in array (PHP array)

Tags: php, arrays, csv, fgetcsv

I'm currently having trouble with reading data from a CSV file. Now it shows the data from the CSV file like this when I print the array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => james;large;33
)
```

However I want it to have it like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => james
    [1] => large
    [2] => 33
)
```

This is the code that I'm using to read data from the CSV file

```
$file = fopen($file, 'r');
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file) ) {
            print "<pre>";
            print_r($row);
            print "</pre>";
    }
```

And this is the CSV file that I'm using:

[image: saved as .csv]

Any suggestions how I can make this work like I want to? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have different delimiter used in CSV rather default which is **,**

[fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php)

you can define delimiter in `fgetcsv` function as a second parameter.

```
$file = fopen($file, 'r');
    while ($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ";") ) {
            print "<pre>";
            print_r($row);
            print "</pre>";
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it was actually **while ($row = fgetcsv($file, 0, ";") )** with the zero

Comment: Thanks For Correction too.